# why am I getting an invalid token standard error?

Tags: javascript, smartcontracts, solana, solana-web3js, metaplex

I want to update the metadata of an NFT using metaplex js library,

I followed the docs but I keep gettin an invalid token standard error.

```
const new_uri = await metaplex.nfts().uploadMetadata(
    uri_obj,
) 

await metaplex.nfts().update({ 
    nftOrSft: nft,
    uri:new_uri.uri
});
```

I created a new storage unit in airweave and got it's url but I keep getting the error
and not just on the url but when I try to change the name for testing purposes aswell.

full error:

```
return resolvedError ? new ProgramError.ParsedProgramError(program, resolvedError, error.logs) : new ProgramError.UnknownProgramError(program, error);
                           ^

ParsedProgramError: The program [TokenMetadataProgram] at address [metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s] raised an error of code [135] that translates to "Invalid token standard".

Source: Program > TokenMetadataProgram [metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s]

Caused By: InvalidTokenStandard: Invalid token standard

Program Logs:
| Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [1]
| Program log: Instruction: Token Metadata Update
| Program log: Invalid token standard
| Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 18628 of 200000 compute units
| Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: custom program error: 0x87
```

here is the uri_object that I'm using

```
{
  name: 'Suteki #467',
  symbol: 'TEKI',
  description: "Suteki is a unique collection of 6000 anime PFP's that focus on community building and creating real-world value. Claim your Buzoku (tribe), follow the lore and work up the ranks of the hierarchy to become a Oyabun (Family boss).",
  seller_fee_basis_points: 900,
  image: 'https://bafybeifsrfzvrms7ptbuv2pjhg3a5lr6waxhd6qyjzpm3ynogs3cbvfcdq.ipfs.nftstorage.link/467.png?ext=png',
  attributes: [
    { trait_type: 'Background', value: 'Sand' },
    { trait_type: 'Type', value: 'Light Scar' },
    { trait_type: 'Tattoo or Scar Small', value: 'Mouth Scar' },
    { trait_type: 'Tattoo or Scar Large', value: 'Suteki Faction' },
    { trait_type: 'Mouth', value: 'Smile' },
    { trait_type: 'Eyes', value: 'Blue' },
    { trait_type: 'EyeBrows', value: 'Raised Right' },
    { trait_type: 'Clothes', value: 'Spike Blazer' },
    { trait_type: 'Mask', value: 'Cloth Wrap Blizzard' },
    { trait_type: 'Hair', value: 'Blue Comb Over' },
    { trait_type: 'Rank', value: 'Shatei (Little Brother)' },
    { trait_type: 'Buzoku', value: 'Akamatsu' }
  ],
  properties: {
    category: 'image',
    files: [ [Object] ],
    creators: [ [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  collection: { name: 'Suteki', family: 'Suteki' }
}
```

Comment: i think `url_obj` does not contain necessary properties. can you paste it

Comment: but I think the problem is not related to just the uri as I'm getting the error whenever I try to update name aswell

Comment: are you able to `console.log(new_uri)`

Comment: What is `nft` here: ` nftOrSft: nft`,